# Does Django close and delete TemporaryUploadedFiles and InMemoryUploadedFiles?

Tags: django, file, django-models, multipartform-data, temporary-files

I have read through all the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/uploads/) for TemporaryUploadedFiles and InMemoryUploadedFiles but they talk never about clean up. I know that Python Temporary Files need to be closed in order to be deleted automatically.

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def test(request):
    #img is type InMemoryUploadedFile
    for img in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
        Model.objects.image = img
        Model.save()

    #vid is type TemporaryUploadedFile
    for vid in request.FILES.getlist('videos'):
        Model.objects.video = vid
        Model.save()
```

In the code above, are the TemporaryUploadedFiles and InMemoryUploadedFiles deleted and cleaned up automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are closed, WSGI handler can provide a method called `close` and that method is called post-processing of the request.

Django source code (http/request.py)

```
class HttpRequest:
  ...
  def close(self):
     if hasattr(self, '_files'):
        for f in chain.from_iterable(list_[1] for list_ in self._files.lists()):
           f.close()
```

Edit:

Django globally configures two types of file uploader InMemory and Temp file. All these classes implement the`close` method, the close method of `request` object is registered as `_resource_closers` and these methods are called from `HttpResponseBase`'s `close` method.

Comment: Is this also true for the InMemoryUploadedFile? Is it cleaned from memory immediately after use?

Comment: In-memory files are closed too.

Comment: This happens without calling .close()?

Comment: WSGI handler will call `request.close` and that will close on the open files.